# Reference for introductory text on Homotopy Theory

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory

Can anyone recommend a good introductory text on Homotopy Theory? Paid textbooks or free online material/lecture notes both welcome.

Comment: These introductory topology books are available online. They should contain a homotopy section.. http://lib.freescienceengineering.org/search.php?search_type=magic&search_text=introduction++topology&submit=Dig+for

Comment: You could try the book 'Algebraic Topology' by Allen Hatcher. Just search for his name and his homepage will show up. There's a free copy of the book available there.